# azure devops pipeline not triggering

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have pipelines.yml file in main branch, whenever there is a change in main branch the pipeline executes without any issues but not for other branches.

It is also working, when I placed the same pipelines.yml copy in other branches as well.
How to avoid keeping same file each branch and trigger whenever there is a change in other branches too.

```yaml
trigger:
  batch: true

  branches:
    include:
    - main
    - dev
  
  paths:
    include:
    - tfroot/env/*/numbers.txt
```

Edit: I am not sure, what is the mistake I am making in yaml pipeline. It is working as expected in classic pipeline, but not in yml.
**classic pipeline trigger**
[image: Working CI]

**Not-Working pipeline**
[image: Yaml pipeline not trigger]

I also tried exporting the classic pipeline as YAML and pasted in other pipeline,the result not changed.

Comment: The pipeline file should be in every branch. Why do you have it in one branch but not in another? I don't think you are using git right.

Comment: @VladDX - My use case is different, I have to trigger the same pipeline but to different subscription based upon the branch I commit. My YAML pipeline is also dynamic to achieve this. But I do not understand or this may be by Microsoft Intention or Issue that CI classic pipeline is able to do but not YAML.

Comment: Branches supposed to be short-lived. How is it possible that you have pipeline YAML file on `main` but don't have it on other branches? You can pass parameters to your pipeline based on a current branch. But it still will be one YAML file for all branches.

Comment: @VladDX - I understood it is not possible in YAML pipeline as the same feature available in Classic Pipeline. I will close this question. I have upvoted your answer too, but not able to accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each branch should contain the yaml file to run your pipeline. Check the documentation:
[Branch consideration for triggers in YAML pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops#branch-consideration-for-triggers-in-yaml-pipelines).

To avoid this, you may use:

1. Classic pipelines (as you mentioned).
2. Use templates. Create a template repository and reference it in your local build yaml. In this case, the local yaml does not have any steps... all your steps are described in the template repo: [Template types & usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)

Comment: In this case, based on parameter specific template can be called.

Answer (score -1):

you may try using template for the branch naming ([Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#wildcards)), linke: `- branch*`

or override your yaml definition:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried both your options, still its same for YAML pipeline, but in classic pipeline it works as expected.

Comment: @DillyB that should work for yaml also because this is an out-of-box feature.